# OpenGL functions are undefined in VS2012 express

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012

I'm attempting to use some OpenGL functions in Visual Studio 2012 express, my code looks like this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <fstream>

void saveScreen()
{
 //code to define some variables, nWidth, nHeight and Buffer.

glreadbuffer ( GL_BACK ); //which buffer we are reading from.
glreadpixels ( 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid *Buffer); 
//do something with buffer data
return;

}
```

According to internet research, my code is correct, apart from glreadpixels apparently expects more expressions and )'s, but i think i can work that out myself.

When i try to compile and run i get errors saying both glreadbuffer and glreadpixels are undefined. I cant find anything that tells me what to do apart from #including windows.h and gl/gl.h and OpenGL should work.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Edit:

Thanks for replying, I added these lines to the Additional dependancys of the linker:

opengl32.lib
glu32.lib

and properly capitalised the function calls
That seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: You need to *link* with the OpenGL library (which provides the *definitions* of the functions) too.

Comment: Just FYI: The case of the OpenGL headers on Windows and non-MacOS X Unix and Linux is `GL/gl.h` not other way round (it doesn't matter on Windows, but on MacOS X it is `OpenGL/gl.h`

Answer (score 0):

The functions `glreadbuffer()` and `glreadpixels` do not exist in OpenGL. The API uses CamelCase function name style, so these function names are spelled `glReadBuffer()` and `glReadPixels()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you correctly link in visual studio 12:

The first thing you create is a folder somewhere called "dev" (or really any name). In that folder you extract "freeglut"(only if you want a windowing toolkit) and "glew" (the openGL extension wrangler, this loads the gl functions).

After that you open a new project in VS12 and rightclick on the project->properties
Under VC++ properties click on "Include directories" and add the path to your dev/glew/include folder and your dev/freeglut/include. Make sure your path is 100% correct!
Then click on "Library directories" and add these 2 paths: dev/glew/lib and dev/freeglut/lib.

Then go to C/C++ and click on additional include directories and add these 2 paths:dev/glew/include and dev/freeglut/include. 
Then go to linker and add the lib folders in "additional library directories" this is a tricky one because you need to link to the correct version: \dev\glew\lib\Release\Win32

Then try your code again, if that doesn't work, try source code from the internet.
Also if you copied the folders without changing there name you should include "GL/glew.h"
These steps are required for each project that uses openGL.